# Getting different eigenvectors for same matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have the same two matrices, one has the input values as integer and the other as real numbers.  Mathematica shows the eigenvectors are completely different for the two same matrices and wondering why....

```
A1 = {{0, 1}, {-2, -3}},

A2 = {{0.0, 1.0}, {-2.0, -3.0}}

{eigenVal1, eigenVec1} = Eigensystem[A1]

{{-2, -1}, {{-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}}

{eigenVal2, eigenVec2} = Eigensystem[A2]

{{-2., -1.}, {{-0.447214, 0.894427}, {0.707107, -0.707107}}}
```

I am using the version 11.2 and thanks for any help.

Comment: The title was a little misleading so I edited it. A difference in eigenvectors for a given matrix is possible; a difference in eigenvalues is a great cause for concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this curious behavior can be found in the documentation for `Eigensystem`:

> For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized.

So, you'll notice that if you normalize the vectors in `eigenVec1` via `N[Normalize /@ eigenVec1]`, you'll produce `eigenVec2`!

I assume the motivation is that if you're working over the integers, you'll want your eigenvectors to be over the integers if possible too.

Comment: Since eigenvector normalization generally produces ugly radicals, it is usually avoided for exact or symbolic matrices. For numerical work, normalization is often desired. In any event, for an eigenvector $\mathbf v$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, $c\mathbf v$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ for $|c|>0$.

Comment: Thank you.  From the "details and options" of the documentation: "For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized."  "For exact or symbolic matrices m, the eigenvectors are not normalized. "  Thanks.